# Qark returns error when I scan an APK files

Tags: python, android, security, pip, penetration-tools

I installed Qark successfully by following the guidance from github.com/linkedin/qark but when I run a scan it returns the error below. Another thing is when I run the scan for a java file everything works well. I'm really confused as to what is causing the error since I can't make sense from it.

For those who may not know, Qark is a tool for evaluating the security for mobile apps.

Below is the error log:

```
Decompiling...
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
-e/-o can only used with one file
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
Input file (Simple_v2.0.74_apkfab.com.apk) was not found or was not readable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/.local/bin/qark", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qark/qark.py", line 87, in cli
    decompiler = Decompiler(path_to_source=source, build_directory=build_path)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qark/decompiler/decompiler.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.manifest_path = self.run_apktool()
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qark/decompiler/decompiler.py", line 163, in run_apktool
    os.path.join(self.build_directory, "AndroidManifest.xml"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 325, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 153, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 96, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kali/qark/build/qark/apktool/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Python 2 by any chance? If so upgrade to Python 3 and you should be good to go. I had a similar issue and Python 2 was the source of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I don't think that will solve it, I have 2 OS running Qark, and I have upgraded the other one to python 3 yet it didn't work well. Is it possible the issue is from the apk file? Because I got the apk file I use for testing online, but when I write a Java program as input, it works well.